# LPC1769 UART reads getting mixed up

Tags: gps, uart, lpc

I have a GPS module connected to an LPC1769. When my software reads them, they're often getting messed up like this:

```
[gps] Parsing: GPGGA,021447.80$GPGGA,021448.800,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*4B
[gps] Parsing: GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
[gps] Parsing: GPGSV,1,1,00*79
[gps] Parsing: GPRMC,021448.800,V,,,,,0.00,0.00,060180,,,N*41
[gps] Parsing: GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32
[gps] GPS location: 231200246:21448, no fix
[gps] Parsing: GPGGA,021449.80$GPGGA,021450.800,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*42
[gps] Parsing: GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
[gps] Parsing: GPRMC,021450.800,V,,,,,0.00,0.00,060180,,,N*48
[gps] Parsing: GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32
[gps] GPS location: 45200246:21450, no fix
[gps] Parsing: GPGGA,021451.80$GPGGA,021452.800,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*40
[gps] Parsing: GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
[gps] Parsing: GPRMC,021452.800,V,,,,,0.00,0.00,060180,,,N*4A
[gps] Parsing: GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,N*32
[gps] GPS location: 135200246:21452, no fix
```

The first sentence of each batch begins with 16 bytes (and it's always 16; my code swallows the initial $ before parsing). My code looks like this:

```c
void gps_task(void) {
    char buffer[128], *ptr;

    locupd_packet_t loc;

    for (;;) {
        while (Uart_ReadChar(3) != '$');
        ptr = buffer;
        while ((*ptr++ = Uart_ReadChar(3)) != '\n');
        *(ptr - 1) = 0;

        Log_Debug("Parsing: %s", buffer);
        // Parse buffer
        Zeptos_Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

If I remove the sleep, the problem only happens on the first update, then all the others read fine. Here's the ReadChar code:

```c
char Uart_ReadChar(int uartn) {
    LPC_UART_TypeDef *uart = uarts[uartn];

    uint32_t status;
    while (((status = uart->LSR) & 1) == 0) {
        if (status & (1 << 1)) Log_Error("RX buffer overflow on UART %i", uartn);
        Zeptos_BlockOnIrq(UART0_IRQn + uartn);
    }

    return uart->RBR & 0xff;
}
```

The `BlockOnIrq` call there returns when the appropriate UART IRQ fires. I check for overflow, but it doesn't happen. Points to note:

- The UART FIFO happens to also be 16 bytes
- The updates are at 1Hz and `021447` etc are timestamps, so can see that every other update is being fully read, with the in-between ones being lost somewhere

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you check for overflow only while the receive buffer is empty.
Try to check the overflow after the cicle before you read the RBR register.